# Whatsapp send message to particular group via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I was wondering it its possible to send message to a particular group in whatsapp via android intents. I found that there is a way to send message to a particular contact(however that just opens the chat window with that particular contact with no message typed in).

Even being able to open a group chat window directly would be enough for me at this stage. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, this is a partial solution:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://chat.whatsapp.com/uniqueId");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

where the link `chat.whatsapp.com/uniqueId` is the join group by link option in the whatsapp group: group > add participant > invite to group via link

This option opens the requested WhatsApp group.